# Trying to display info from database but nothing is showing up - WordPress/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to show a list of custom post types on a page template. When I view the page, instead of seeing the different posts, I see the actual page repeated. For example, If I have 5 posts, the actual page (head content footer) will be display five times. It seems like the query is working...in some way but I am not sure what is wrong. Here is the template code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('page'); ?>>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <article>

            <div class="post-content page-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="pagination">&after=</div>'); ?>
            </div><!--.post-content .page-content -->

        </article>

    </div><!--#post-# .post-->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- Start search result code -->

<?php
//query_posts('post_type=listing&orderby=title&order=ASC&posts_per_page=9999');
?>

<?php
$querystr = "
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postsmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'listing_open' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'YES'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing'
ORDER BY post_title
";                              
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);                         
if ($pageposts):                    
foreach ($pageposts as $postdata):
setup_postdata($postdata);
?>

<?php //if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php include_once(get_bloginfo('template_url')."/layout-listings.php?id=".$postdata->ID); ?>       

<?php //endwhile; endif; rewind_posts(); wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php
endforeach;
endif;
?>

<?php
$querystr = "
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'listing_open' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'NO'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing'
ORDER BY post_title
";                              
$pageposts2 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);                            
if ($pageposts2):                    
foreach ($pageposts2 as $postdata2):
setup_postdata($postdata2);
?>

<?php //if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php include_once(get_bloginfo('template_url')."/layout-listings.php?id=".$postdata2->ID); ?>      

<?php //endwhile; endif; rewind_posts(); wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php
endforeach;
endif;
?>

<!-- End search result code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to attend in that code.

### Proper [`include_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) usage

You have to include the route of the file in disk, not the public url. Something like:

```
include_once(get_stylesheet_directory() . "/layout-listings.php");
```

or better yet, use [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_template_part):

```
get_template_part('layout', 'listings');
```

### Use [`get_posts` or `new WP_Query`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) instead of doing explicit queries

You should try to use queries only when there is no other choice, use get_posts instead:

```
$pageposts2 = new WP_Query(array(
  'meta_key'   => 'listing_open',
  'meta_value' => 'NO'
));
```

The code above will get the results you need.

Pros about using wordpress functions:

- wordpress cache
- compatibility with third party plugins, like as multilanguage plugins
- pagination

If the query is too complex for [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query), you should also consider reading about [protecting queries against SQL injection attacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

** be careful using [`query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/33558)

### Typos?

You got the `if`, `while`, `the_post`, `rewind_posts` and `wp_reset_query` functions commented.